# C# WPF DataGrid change cell icon resource programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've never used a DataGrid in C# before (and done little C#) and I'm struggling to change a DataGrid cell icon I've set in XAML. By default its set to a Dynamic resource of appbar_question and upon certain conditions being met I'd like to be able to change it to a resource of appbar_check (I'm using the mahapps icons).

XAML code

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterMe}" Header="Website" Binding="{Binding Website}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterMe}" Header="Status" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="ShowStatus">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_question}" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

First I tried to access the cell directly but I see DataGrids in WPF like you to bind to an object(s) then access them as items and change properties in that object. However I tried doing that but couldn't figure out how to bind to a resource in my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use DataTemplate.Triggers:
  1. Name your VisualBrush:

```
     <VisualBrush x:Name="myBrush"...
```

2. Add DataTemplate.Triggers:

   ```
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding to_my_property}" Value="my_condition">
         <Setter TargetName="myBrush" Property="Visual" Value="{DynamicResource appbar_check}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
   ```

Hope it helps.